# How keccak hashing and for loop happening in pure function?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, hash, keyword

I put a keccak hashing inside `pure` function, it works and return me the result.It also works in a `for` loop. I studied that hashing the data and loop consumes consider amount of gas. Do we need to provide ether for that??. But pure function invocation doesn't go as a transaction right... ??

Comment: This answer gives me the more clearer explanation. [Read only function iteration cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755578/read-only-functions-iteration-cost)

Answer (score 0):

`pure` functions *do* consume gas if they are being called on-chain.

If you are calling the `pure` function off-chain (e.g. for the frontend of your website), there is no associated cost. If you are calling the `pure` function on-chain as a part of a transaction, it will consume gas.

Comment: "if they are being called on-chain" - from a function which is **not `pure` or `view`**!

Comment: @shane Thats what my question is about.. Why the off-chain call doesn't cost gas?. EVM has to do the computation, Irrespective of the origin right?.

Comment: @goodvibration It will cost gas if it is not pure or view. That's what my question also. Anyway computation done by EVM is same on both cases.